# iOS In-App purchase Testing: How to do alpha testing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have created ios app with Auto-Renewable Subscription. I can able to test that using Sandbox account environment. 
**Is there any option to test it like Alpha testing?** . `ie Specific user can view my app in AppStore and test the inapp purchase with real account details and do cancel subscription`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, no.

There are no any provided ways to do this. Sandbox mode only. If your app has not live yet AppStore is not able to communicate with bank account.

Comment: But you might be sure with sandbox testing